# Register .NET Framework 4.5 in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, iis-7.5, windows-7-x64, asp.net-4.5

Pieces of the puzzle:

- Windows 7
- .NET Framework 4.5 (installed)
- IIS 7(Version 7.5.7600.16385)
- Visual Studio (Ultimate 2013)
- MVC4 (multiple projects in the solution)

The solution I'm running in Visual Studio works and runs as expected with IISExpress.

To set up my site to use IIS, I tried the following steps:

1. Right-click the projects in the solution that are currently being hosted by IISExpress.
2. Click Properties.
3. Toggle the Servers drop-down from IISExpress to Local IIS
4. Try to build/run the application

At this point, I get an `HTTP 500.21` error.

I have also tried to run `aspnet_regiis.exe -i` using Visual Studio's command prompt (as an Administrator), but each time I run the command, I receive the following error:

> Command 'aspnet_regiis.exe' is not valid.

I also confirmed that I do have the right `aspnet_regiis.exe` installed (by checking [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX#findingthecorrectversion)) (.NET Framework version 4 (64-bit systems)).

What do I need to do to register .NET Framework 4.5 in IIS 7.5?

Comment: I also hit this after I installed the VS2015 CTP. The fix for me was to uninstall the CTP, along with the .NET preview version it brought with it. I then reinstalled .NET 4.5.1 and the message went away.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can find the aspnet_regiis in the following directory:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

Go to the directory and run the command form there. I guess the path is missing in your PATH variable.

Comment: Per the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX#findingthecorrectversion) in my original post I already knew that I had the correct version of _aspnet_regiis.exe_ but what the documentation doesn't plainly (if at all) state is what you (@peer) explained in your response. The fix for me was to 1) open _cmd_ as an administrator. 2) `cd \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319` 3) `aspnet_regiis.exe -i`. Good to go, thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Hosting asp.net 4.5/4.5.1 Web application on Local IIS
  1)Be Sure
  IIS Installation before Visual Installation Installataion then aspnet_regiis will already registerd with IIS

If Not Install IIS and then Register aspnet_regiis with IIS by cmd Editor

For VS2012 and 32 bit OS Run Below code on command editor :

1)Install IIS First & then

2)

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319   

  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319> aspnet_regiis -i
```

For VS2012 and 64 bit OS Below code on command editor:

1)Install IIS First & then

2)

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319    
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319> aspnet_regiis -i
```

BY Following Above Steps Current Version of VS2012 registered with IIS
 **Hosting (VS2012 Web APP)**

Create VS2012 Web Application(WebForm/MVC) then Build Application
    Right Click On WebApplication(WebForm/MVC) go to 'Properties'
    Click On 'Web' Tab on then 'Use Local IIS Web Server'
    Then Uncheck 'Use IIS Express' 
    (If Visul Studio 2013 Select 'Local IIS' from Dropdown)
    Provide Project Url like "http://localhost/MvcDemoApp"
    Then Click On 'Create Virtual Directory' Button
    Then Open IIS by Prssing 'Window + R' Run Command and type 'inetmgr' and 'Enter' (or 'OK' Button)
    Then Expand 'Sites->Default Web Site' you Hosted Successfully.
    If Still Gets any Server Error 
       like 'The resource cannot be found.' 
    Then Include following code in web.config

```
 <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
         <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>

And Run Application
```

If still problem occurs
Check application pool by : In iis Right click on application->Manage Application->Advanced setting->General. you see the application pool.
then close advance setting window.
click on 'Application Pools' you will see the all application pools in middle window.
Right click on application pool in which application hosted(DefaultAppPool).
click 'Basic Setting' -> Change .Net FrameWork Version to->.Net FrameWork v4.0.30349

Answer (score 4):

For Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 use `dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45`
As administrative command prompt.

Comment: Not the answer, but very helpful.

Comment: If you want to query the current state, do this: ```dism /Online /Get-FeatureInfo /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45```

Answer (score 1):

I got into this mess twice and after searching long and hard and following what others did absolutely nothing worked for me but to uninstall and install IIS back once on Windows 7 machine and then on Windows server 2012 R2.

Comment: Thanks for the tip however the original post doesn't use or mention Windows Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score -1):

use .NET3.5 it worked for me for similar issue.

Comment: This does not attempt to resolve the issue OP is asking about.